# grep to match entire certificate?

Tags: regex, ubuntu, awk, sed, grep

I am running a command that generate certificate request like this,

```
some text
some text
certificate is -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----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-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

I want to save the certificate automatically into a file but not the text `certificate is` or any lines before that.

Right now i am using `command | grep -A100 "\-----BEGIN"` to get all lines and saving it to file but I am just using `100` as number of lines, but the certificate is not `100` lines. How can I get exact number of lines including and after `-----BEGIN` so I can write certificate to a file?

Edit: I also just tried this, `command | grep -A$(wc -l) "\-----BEGIN"` but it doesn't print anything at all

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----.*-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----' 'RT{print RT}' file
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----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-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

With any awk:

```
$ awk -v beg='-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----' -v end='-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----' 'sub(".*"beg,beg){f=1} f; sub(end".*",end){exit}' file
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----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-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

Comment: nice one using AWK :-)

Answer (score 4):

A Solution with regex and `grep`:

```
command| grep  -zo -- "-*BEGIN.*END.*-*$"
```

- `-z` is to eliminate new line character(`\n`), so we can match patterns in multi-line.
- `-o` is to only print matched text.
- `--` is to escape the first dash.

Another solution, using GNU `awk`:

```
command| awk -v RS="[\t ]" -v b=0 -v ORS=" " '/-----BEGIN/{b=1;print;next} b{print}'
```

Comment: i tried it but there is other lines before `certificate is`, those are still printing

Comment: I added another solution, I'm assuming that file ends with `-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----`, also I think that this solution could be inefficient in memory, because it charges all command output to memory.

Comment: I added a solution with grep, that's possibly what you're searching.

Comment: You should mention that the awk solution  requires GNU awk for multi-char RS. Any other awk would use the char `[` as the RS value given your script.

Answer (score 3):

**sed**

```
 Command | sed -n '/BEGIN.*-/,/END.*-/p' | grep -v -
```

1) `sed -n '/BEGIN.*-/,/END.*-/p'` - display all lines between both strings `BEGIN.*-` & `END.*-` .

- `-n` - suppress automatic printing of pattern space.
- `/begin string/,/end string/` - all chars between begin & end string
- `p` - Print the current pattern space.

2) `grep -v -` - remove unnecessary lines (BEGIN & END lines)

Answer (score 1):

Using `pcregrep` (works also in macOS/BSD):

```
command | pcregrep -Mo "\-{5}BEGIN*(\n|.)*REQUEST\-{5}"
```

or with `grep`:

```
command | grep -zoP "\-{5}BEGIN*(\n|.)*REQUEST\-{5}"
```